# How to set default file type to be All Files(*.*) in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Now my default file type of Visual Studio Code is `Plain Text`.

If I save a new file with name like `a.in`, it will save as `a.in.txt`. I have to change the dropdown to `All Files`.

I find the same problems in github: [1](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44819), [2](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28425). However, they seem not solve my problem.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: "This" = your question "How to set default file type to be All Files(*.*) in VS Code?"

Comment: @namasikanam, please see my answer. it provides a partial solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in the general case in VSCode.
The issue is that you cannot assign "no extension" to a language, and as per the links you mentioned, the `All Files (*.*)` option is [disabled by upstream (electron)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28425#issuecomment-515732764).

Therefore, you will either have to remove the extension manually, OR you can create the file first (using the terminal, Explorer, an extension, etc.) and then open that existing file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change the default extension (but not to *All Files*)

Add the following line to your [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

```json
"files.defaultLanguage": "<language>",
```

Replace `<language>` with the language of your choice.
Now, whenever you make a new a file, the default file language will be `<language>`.

A special value for `<language>` is `${activeEditorLanguage}` which is the language of the file last opened (useful if, say, you copy a piece of code from one file to save as another).

Unfortunately, this does not fully answer the question, but provides a partial solution.